# Is there a way to loop ARMA function that changes 'x' in arma(x, order=c(1,1))

Tags: r, loops, statistics, arima

I am trying to estimate ARMA (1,1) on different subset of data, adding a month on every time but a little stuck on how to create the loop arma(x, order=c(1,1)) so want x to increase by 1 month each time to get out-of-sample forecasting

So ideally want to keep looping arma to get different outputs according to the extra month added on so x+1 just stuck on how to actually create a loop which keeps adding a month on

Comment: you can loop the index: `arma(x[1:i])` and `i` runs from 1  to n.
Maybe we can be of better help if you share your data with us.

Comment: so the data is monthly 1960 to 2018 growth rates, using the data up til December 2012  to do out of sample forecast using ARMA (1,1) , so using data uptil December 2012 to forecast January 2013 using the output of ARMA then I wanted to carry on the ARMA calculations by adding an extra month on each time to get all the forecasts til December 2018 so I would presume it would be a loop of 72! sorry if this a little confusing!